# Proving that a function is constant if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} (x) = 0 \ \ \ \forall {j \in \text{{1,...,n}}} \ \ \ \forall x \in U $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $I_1,...,I_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open intervals and $U := I_1 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times I_n \subset \mathbb{R^n}.$

Further, let $\text { }f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is partially derivable on all points with

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} (x) = 0 \ \ \ \forall {j \in \text{{1,...,n}}} \ \ \ \forall x \in U $$

**How can I show, that $f$ is constant?**

So far I got this:

We take two generic points $x = (x_1, ...., x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,....,y_n) \in U.$

We want to show that $f(x) = f(y).$

Therefore we define the points $a_0 := y$, $a_n := x$, as well as $a_k := (x_1,....,x_k, y_{k+1},....,y_n) \text { for } 1 \leq k \leq n - 1.$

Now (for $k\in \text{{1,...,n}})$ we look at the functions $f_k: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_k(t) := f(a_{k-1} + t(x_k - y_k)e_k)$, where $e_k$ is the k-th unit vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

How can I show now, that $f'_k \equiv 0$ for all $k$, from which we can say that all functions $f_k$ are constant? So, $f(a_{k-1}) = f_k(0) = f_k(1) = f(a_k) \text{ for all } k \in$ {$1,...,n$}. I have to deduce now that $f$ is constant.

And how can one conclude from above, that $\arctan (\frac{x}{y}) + \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x,y > 0$?

I know that  $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$, but I don't know how to conclude $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from what is given above.

Comment: This is just a thought, but since you have that all the partial derivatives are zero in your intervals, then the directional derivative is zero in every direction. So your function can't be increasing or decreasing anywhere and hence is a constant.

Comment: Your problem should follow from the single-variable case, since you can separately show $f$ is constant along lines parallel to the axes, and you can connect any two points along such lines, as you have done.  The single variable case should follow from the Mean Value Theorem.  Finally, for your second question, presumably the idea is to let $f(x,y)$ be the function given by the expression on the left-hand side.  Then show that all the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish at each point.  Then apply your first result....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, define $f(x,y) = \arctan \frac xy + \arctan \frac yx$ on the quarter-space $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$.  Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{1 + (\frac xy)^2} \cdot \frac 1y + \frac{1}{1 + (\frac yx)^2} \cdot \frac{-y}{x^2} = 0$$
after a bit of simplification. Since $f$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ you get also that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, so that $f$ is constant.

It follows that $f(x,y) = f(1,1) = \dfrac \pi 2$ for all $x,y > 0$.